# Execute script in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Can you execute, say a PHP script from a stored procedure in a MySQL database? Or are you limited purely to internal / custom database functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question : No

Second question : Depends

```
mysql> \! php -r "echo 1;";
1    "> /* <-- results from php */
```

However, I don't think is advisable to this ...

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you can do that, but as you know you can execute a stored procedure from PHP.  But even if its possible, I wouldn't do it.  For some reason it seems like you're trying to solve your problem the wrong way.